# FTP server vsftpd - Can connect but can't see any file

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

Here is the content of my config file `/etc/init.d/vsftpd` :

```
listen=YES
local_enable=YES
local_root=/
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
```

And here is [what I see...](ftp://ludivisites.fr)

As you can see, I don't see much, and I believe I should. 
Any suggestion is most welcome.

Comment: With an anonymous login I see an empty directory, so your FTP server works, but you probably need to specify an [ `anon_root`](http://vsftpd.beasts.org/vsftpd_conf.html) directory to have the right contents appear (and setting it to `/` is not the best)

Comment: I understood. Based on this, I ended up understanding that my final problem was that the user's directory didn't exists for the user I wanted to login with. 

To be more specific, I wanted to log with user `alex`, and `/home/alex` didn't exist, so it was not working. Everything is now working fine! Thanks a lot for pointing the way. You made me understand that the arrival directory was the key to my FTP issues